# Manipulating and analysing 4-line data from file

Tags: c, macos, terminal, while-loop

I need to sort out a set of 4 lines of data in a text file, e.g..

```
[DATA]
[DATA]
[DATA]
[DATA]
[BLANK LINE]
[DATA]
....
```

My problem is that my below function ends up working if there is only one set of 4-line data but it freezes when there is more than one set. What might have caused the issue? Please let me know if you need more of the code.

Many thanks.

```
int i=0;
while(i < (numGames + empLines))
{
    fgets(gameLine, sizeof(gameLine), input2);
    if (gameLine[0] == '\n')
    {
        continue;
    }
    sscanf(gameLine, "%s %d %d %s %d %d", teamName1, &teamGoal1, &teamBehind1, teamName2, &teamGoal2, &teamBehind2);
    int j =0;
    while (j < numTeams)
    {



                                          ...



                 }
                k++;
            }
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Nowhere near enough info to help. Don't just add more code though, try to narrow down the problem and print the problematic parts.  Adding printfs() to see where you are getting to is a good first step.

Comment: @John3136 i have added printfs() throughout the code and I've found that the code does not want to exit the while loop when there is more than one set of 4-line data and so freezes.

Comment: None of that is shown in your sample. Which while loop is the problem: first or second? how are numGames, empLines, and numTeams set? There is a `break` in the middle of nowhere: what loop is this breaking?

Comment: We all know that a `for` loop can be implemented as a `while` loop, and you shown it wonderfully here. But may I ask why?

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure the empty line is really empty? No other spaces or tabs? The newline is really a `'\n'` and not `"\r\n"` (UNIX versus Windows line endings)?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I don't know that this is the answer, but from your code:

```
while(i < (numGames + empLines))
{
    fgets(gameLine, sizeof(gameLine), input2);
    if (gameLine[0] == '\n')
    {
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

If the last line of the file is just a '\n', it appears you will loop forever. i will never get incremented and you aren't checking for feof() or looking at the fgets() return value.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is with how the program parses the New Line character for the blank line. It is not necessary that '\n' occurs as the first character of the text file, change the way how your program reads the line first. Like for example, determine if it is a data line, or a blank line by using fgetc() until '\n' or '\r' is encountered. If a non-terminating character is encountered, it is a data line, rewind the pointer to the start of the line and read as formatted string.

Hope it helps :)